# Multiple dependencies with files having same path

Tags: android

Say I have two jars, one `a.jar` with a config file `c.conf` and another `b.jar` with a config file of the same name `c.conf`. The mentioned file is present top level in the jars and is different for both of them. Now if I build an android app with both the jars as dependencies it will obviously fail as there would be two files with same path.

What is the standard way to go about if there are multiple dependencies that depend on a file of same name? What are my options for packaging it? The conf files are absolutely required and `merge` as a packaging option won't work for my case.